# Google AppScript cannot match number of columns in data with number of columns in range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Getting an error at line22.

> Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 6.

```
function getVal() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("nav1");
    const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('nav1');
  
  var url = "";
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var lines = html.split('\n');
  
  var sheet = []
  sheet.push(lines[0].split(';'))
  lines.forEach(function(line) {
  if (!isNaN(line[0]) && line[0] != " "  && line[0] != "\r"){
      var scheme = line.split(';')
      
      sheet.push(scheme)
   }
  });
  targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.length, sheet[0].length).setValues(sheet);
  
}
```

Couldn't get an solution from previous posted similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your value of `html`, it seems that a line of `360 ONE Mutual Fund (Formerly Known as IIFL Mutual Fund)` is existing. In your current script, this line becomes `true` with `if (!isNaN(line[0]) && line[0] != " "  && line[0] != "\r"){}`. By this, each array length in your value of `sheet` is not the same length. I thought that this is the reason for your current issue. In your value, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (!isNaN(line[0]) && line[0] != " "  && line[0] != "\r"){
```

#### To:

```
if (!isNaN(line[0]) && line[0] != " " && line[0] != "\r" && line.includes(";")) {
```

or, following modification might be able to be used.

```
function getVal() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('nav1');
  var url = "https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt";
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var lines = html.split('\n');
  var sheet = []
  lines.forEach(function (line) {
    if (line.includes(";")) {
      var scheme = line.split(';');
      sheet.push(scheme);
    }
  });
  targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.length, sheet[0].length).setValues(sheet);
}
```

- By this, the line of `360 ONE Mutual Fund (Formerly Known as IIFL Mutual Fund)` could be also skipped.
- As another information, I thought that in your script, `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("nav1");` might be able to be removed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It works. But the column data A to E is repeated in G-J. (K is date, which is fine)

Comment: @rncb Thank you for replying. From `It works.`, I understood that your issue of `Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 6` was resolved. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `But the column data A to E is repeated in G-J. (K is date, which is fine)`. But, I would like to support you. So, in order to correctly understand `But the column data A to E is repeated in G-J. (K is date, which is fine)`, can you provide the detail of it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. your modification code works fine. Solved.

Comment: @rncb Thank you for replying and testing again. From `Thanks for the response. your modification code works fine. Solved.`, I understood that your issue was resolved. I'm glad about it.